# What are these cubbies?

Tags: france, architecture

My brother-in-law sent me these pictures from Vitrolles, France. They would have been taken somewhere with in a two hours drive from there.

We were both wondering why in the interior of this tower he saw had all these little cubbies.  Sorry I don't know any more details about the tower, nor do I have outside pictures ( I wish I did. )

I would guess that it was just a way to save on material, but I would love to know for sure why the tower was built this way, or perhaps what it is called so that I can more easily find info on it.

[image: Tower inside by door]

[image: tower inside]

Comment: What is this? A skyscraper for ants?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be the inside of a former "colombier" or "pigeonnier" - i.e. a [dovecote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dovecote).

Assuming so, the holes are there for the doves or pigeons to nest.

Comment: interesting,  That would be a lot of pigeons.

Comment: The region is known to have them, [a photo here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Pigeonnier_Vitrolles_en_Luberon.JPG). And a NY Times [article](https://www.nytimes.com/1990/04/01/travel/homing-in-on-pigeon-towers.html) discussing some.

Comment: I looked up pigeonnier in France and was able to find a couple of pictures of pigeonniers with an equally large number of cubbies.  So your right it seems likely.    Thank you so much!